# Spring Security 3.2.0 port mapping from property file

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc

i have a question regarding Spring Security 3.2.0 and how to modify the port-mapping from property file.

The schema for the security configuration allows only integer for the http and https property.

```
<port-mappings>
<port-mapping http="8090" https="9443" />
</port-mappings>
```

but, it would be great if we could externalize this configuration to a property file like:

```
<security:port-mappings>
<security:port-mapping http="${http.port}" https="${https.port}"/>
</security:port-mappings>

port.properties
---------------------
http.port=8090
https.port=9443
```

Anyone know how it is possible to do that??

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432663/how-can-i-use-a-custom-configured-remembermeauthenticationfilter-in-spring-secur ? 
<code><security:port-mapping http="#{configurationService.configuration.getProperty('tomcat.http.port')}"
            https="#{configurationService.configuration.getProperty('tomcat.ssl.port')}" /></code>

Comment: Thanks for the Input, but where and how is defined the configurationService?

Comment: that is spring SPEL resolving. See the docs http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef